# How can I prevent race conditions using Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I used Only Redis as my DB, and my client is ServiceStack.Redis. The thing is, if two concurrent request need to update one key, then it can be a race condition. For example

A:

1. int a = Get key
2. MULTI
3. a = a - 100
4. Set key a
5. EXEC

B:

1. int a = Get key
2. MULTI
3. a = a - 100
4. Set key a
5. EXEC

if the origin "key" is 1000. If speration A and B are serialized, the right results of this two operations of "key" will be 800. But if A and B happens in the same time. Before A can commit, Operation B get value 1000 from "key", and set 900 to "key". That's not what I want. How can I prevent this kind of race conditions, use "WATCH"?

Answer (score 20):

You should read the docs on [Transactions in Redis](http://redis.io/topics/transactions), transactions in Redis is essentially batching multiple operations so they're executed as a single atomic operation.

Since it's only batching operations, you cannot perform any reads within the context of a transaction. Any reads you need before hand need to be retrieved before the start of the transaction. You can then use the [Redis WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/WATCH) to watch for any keys that shouldn't be modified before your transaction completes, if a key was modified the transaction will fail and no operations will be processed.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that. In my program, I read before starting a transaction in my program. I have changed my pseudo code to a right order. So, WATCH should solve my problem?

Comment: @AllanYang Yes using WATCH before any reads will ensure the transaction wont be executed if the key was modified before the transaction has executed.

Answer (score 0):

@NoobEditor No, just using watch will not help you with a race condition. Watch-exec will guarantee that the entire batch will run iff the watched key is not updated by someone else.

Make use of Redis distributed locks to handle race conditions correctly.